# Some of my pages in my Magento setup redirect to themselves

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

For some reason many of my Magento pages don't work. I get a Internal Server error when I try to load the pages. When looking at the logs I get a infinite redirect.

I have no idea why it's doing this. Any ideas?

I haven't touch the PHP or anything.

For some reason I am able to access the admin section and the Home page. Nothing else works.

I am using a share host.

Comment: Have you tried disabling Webserver rewrites? `System > Configuration > Web > SEO > Use webserver rewrites` and the renaming the `.htaccess` file in your root directory. Might be an issue there.

Comment: I had to change the RewriteBase. This is what was missing.

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins - can you set that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this problem you need to make sure that you have the .htaccess file and to make sure the RewriteBase is well configured.